# Lowest exponent of a CRC polynomial

Tags: crc, polynomials

I have never seen a CRC polynomial without the lowest term x⁰ = 1.

Are there any exceptions I haven't seen yet?
Why do all CRC polynomials have the lowest term x⁰?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CRC polynomial of the form x<sup>n</sup> + ... + x<sup>0</sup> is used for a n bit CRC (it is used with a borrowless divide of the data bits by the CRC polynomial that produces an n bit remainder, the CRC). If the CRC polynomial is of the form x<sup>n</sup> + ... + x<sup>1</sup> (no x<sup>0</sup> term), then it is effectively a n-1 bit CRC.

However, there are cases where common code may use different tables for fast computations of 32 bit or 16 bit CRC's, where the only difference in the main part of the code is the constants. The code is written as if the CRC is of the form x<sup>32</sup> + ... + x<sup>0</sup>, but to allow most of the same code to generate a 16 bit CRC, the polynomial is of the form x<sup>32</sup> + ... + x<sup>16</sup>. There's a final step correction done to shift the final CRC right by 16 bits to place the 16 bit CRC in the proper bits. An example of this is in this 500+ line [fast crc32/16 assembly](https://github.com/01org/isa-l/blob/master/crc/crc16_t10dif_01.asm) example using pclmulqdq insruction (carryless multiply), which in this case is setup to produce a 16 bit CRC.